# Receber um status e marcar como CHECKED - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular-material

Estou recebendo um array do back, contendo os usuários do sistema. 
Eu exibo esse array numa tela de edição de grupos, onde exibe todos os usuários do sistema em um checkbox multiple.

O que preciso fazer e não estou conseguindo: ao exibir o checkbox com todos os usuários do sistema, gostaria que os que já fazem parte deste grupo apareçam como checked, enquanto os que não pertecem, não.

Através de uma rota, eu tenho acesso a todas as informações dos grupos, incluindo quais usuários fazem parte dele.

Como consigo comparar o array de usuários que fazem parte do grupo com o array de todos os usuarios do sistema, marcando como checked quando forem iguais?

Como eu recebo o array de todos os usuarios do sistema:

```
this.groupService.getPermissions().subscribe(
        (result: Permissions[]) => {
          this.listaPermissions = result;
          console.log(result);
          },
        (err) => {console.log(err); }
      );
```

HTML

```
<!-- EXIBE LISTA DE USUÁRIOS -->
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select id=arrayUser placeholder="Usuários"
      matNativeControl multiple>
        <mat-option [value]="item.ID_PROFH" *ngFor="let item of arrayUser; let i=index" 
        (onSelectionChange)="changeArrayIDUser(i, item.ID_PROFH, $event)">{{item.USERNAME}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Lucas, existem algoritmos variados para isto. Mas a princípio para seguir a lógica de negócios e fazer com que o computador execute a rotina que você manda ele executar, faça um loop do tipo "for" ou "foreach" no array de itens recebidos comparando o que se recebeu com o que está por vir e então você faz as adições e os "checked" manualmente se der match na sua comparação.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.arrayDeTodosOsUsuarios.forEach(userGeral => {
this.arrayUsuariosGrupo.forEach(userGrupo => {
if(userGeral.id === userGrupo.id) { // Certifica se é o mesmo usuário nos dois arrays.
userGeral.valorCheckBox = userGrupo.valorCheckBox; // Valor booleano do checkbox, [checked]
}
});
});
```

Existem outras formas de fazer isso, mas acredito que essa deve suprir a sua necessidade, qualquer coisa comenta ai que vamos ajeitando. Não sei tbm se essa é a forma mais otimizada de se fazer isso. Talvez com um .find() no arrayUsuariosGrupo fique melhor.

Answer (score 0):

O ideia seria você colocar uma propriedade [checked]="usuarioChecked" ou algo que venha do backend dizendo que esse usuário foi checkado, dai você coloca ele pra isso, ou você pode utilizar o reactive forms segue esse [exemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-teste?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) de alguns checkebox...